# Passing a vector by reference

Tags: c++, vector, return

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void init()
{       
    std::vector<double> b;
    b.push_back(10);
    return;
}

double mean(double *array, size_t n)
{
    double m=0;
    for(size_t i=0; i<n; ++i)
    {
        m += array[i];
    }
    std::cout<<*array<<std::endl;
    return m/n;
}

int test(int *b)
{
    int dist;
    dist=b[0];
    return dist;
}

int main()
{
    int x=0;
    int y=0;
    //double a[5]={1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    std::vector<double> a;
    a.push_back(1);
    a.push_back(2);
    a.push_back(3);
    a.push_back(4);
    a.push_back(5);
    std::cout<<mean(&a[0], 5)<<std::endl;    // will print 3
    init();
    y=test(&b[0]);
    std::cout<<y<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to check if I can initialize vector "b" in "init" function and retrieve value in "test" function to finally return as "y" in main function. Is this even possible? It is just a test code to explore this possibility.

Comment: It's hard to know where to start, why is `main` declared as `int main(int *b)`? What do you expect `b` to hold here? `main` either has no arguments or exactly two, an `int` and a `char*`.

Comment: `b` in init() no longer exists after init() ends. It also has no connection to the `b` in `main()` or the  `b` in `test()`.

Comment: I see, so i should return "b" to main function as "return = init()". My question is: What is the role of init() in main function in its current form?

Comment: *No syntax error* simply means it compiles..Compiling has no bearing on whether the code executes properly; it just means the code meets the syntax requirements. That fact means that your title is pretty meaningless (Exe file crashes). You should edit your title to be more specific. You've done a nice job of creating a minimal amount of code to demonstrate the problem - kudos for doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want:

```
std::vector<double> init()
{       
    std::vector<double> b;
    b.push_back(10);
    return b;
}
```

and then in main:

```
auto b = init();
y = test( &b.at(0) );
```

When calling `mean`. get the size as `a.size()` instead of hardcoding the 5. And pass `a.data()` instead of `&a[0]`, then it won't crash if the vector is empty.

Comment: Useful tips! I modified my code above to reflect the recommended improvements.

Comment: @Far it would be better to leave your question text unchanged, otherwise it is confusing to new readers. (Edit your post and use the "rollback" feature). You can accept this answer if it answers your question, or you can edit or comment to clarify your intention.

Comment: I rolled back the changes.

Comment: @Far there's a link called "rollback" on top of each past edit.. I did that now (you missed some changes in your manual rollback attempt)